# Prevent libvirtd to use dnsmasq

Tags: libvirt

I'm not using libvirtd/virsh networking at all in my KVM/QEMU setup and libvirtd give the following error when starting

```
Jan 21 06:05:45 srvtest1 libvirtd[1494]: Unable to find 'dnsmasq' binary in $PATH: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to disable/remove the default network, but it doesn't help.

I can install `dnsmasq-base` to solve the problem, it's only 1MB, but I would prefer to tell libvirtd to not look for it at all?

UPDATE:
Workaround, as sugested by paladin, just create the script `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq`

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a dummy, will be called by virtlibd (dnsmasq --version)
echo "Dnsmasq version 2.89"
exit 0
```

Comment: You could create a small executable script, name it `dnsmasq` and place it in `/usr/sbin/` with contents: Line 1: `#!/bin/sh` Line 2: `# this is a dummy, exit 5 is used for "Other miscellaneous problem.", see man dnsmasq` Line 3: `exit 5` ;-) - or you could just ignore the problem

Comment: Nice work around :-) Do you know, as a fact,  that it cannot be disabled, i.e. it is hard-coded in libvirtd?

Comment: No, I don't know this. But as `dnsmasq` is a wide spread tool, the programmers of `libvirtd` have porbably just forget to make some additional error checkings. You might send a bug report to the developers of `libvirtd`, would help them to improve.